# Elements cutting out of scrollbar

Tags: css

Here's an example of what is happening: https://jsfiddle.net/fz5asxn6/

If you hit 'Click Me' and the Add button a few times you can see items added but the bottom ones are being cutoff and I can't see the bottom of the scrollbar.

I've tried setting the `overflow` property, `flex-flow`, and `table`.

Is there any way to see have the `options-body` take up the whole `options` inside the `sidebar` without cutting anything off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, that confused me. I saw your bug and when I opened the dev tools it was gone. It took me a while to realize your media query was changing things based on the height. But that showed me the bug immediately.

Your sidebar has a `height: 100%;` and a `margin-top: 60px;`.
Try setting `margin-top:0;` then you see that this causes the issue.

I suggest setting `height: calc(100% - 60px);`

And in your media query `height: calc(100% - 15px);`

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Sorry, I should have pointed out the media query.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.sidebar`

This will tell the browser to calculate the total height from the border, not the content, and thus the 100% height would include the padding.

So your css for .sidebar would become:

```
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Updated Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nabtron/Lznrfcyv/1/

I hope it helps.